# Edit incoming request body payloads in flask api

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

Im looking to make my Flask based API case insensitive for all incoming payloads. rather than having to apply this to all api-route functions i want to apply this to the `@app.before_request` decorator, such that for all incoming requests with json payloads (POSTs and PUTs) I directly edit the payload before it is handled by the applicable `app.route` function.

`POST {"x":1, "Y":2}` Should be formatted to `POST {"x":1, "y":2}` for request endpoints, but I can't seem to make this happen.

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    if request.json:
        data = RecusivelyLowerKeys(request.get_json())
        request.data = json.dumps(ldata)
```

so far this approach hasn't worked and the original request payload seems static.

Any tips or alternative approaches would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: As someone would built and consumed many REST APIs I advise to keep the API case sensitive and use is properly instead. Just like your `RecusivelyLowerKeys` which is used like a function and is confusingly capitalized like a class.

Comment: I'm well aware that this is not standard. My API is not intended for public use and case insensitivity has been requested by a client.